# Cant get data from Api in php, the api have the data in json format

Tags: php, rest

here is code example
use both PHP built-in function file_get_contents() / CURL commands.

```
$api_url = 'https://api.tg3ds.com/api/v1/scan_records?apikey=1sjQKWfPpdyxRBvfv2BuTl5JzexOIScCFN0t&limit=20&offset=0&sort=scanned_at&user_id=PGLY1096&unfold=true&filter=PGLY1096';
// Read JSON file
$json_data = file_get_contents($api_url);
// Decode JSON data into PHP array
$response_data = json_decode($json_data);
var_dump($response_data);
exit();
```

As cURL

```
        // create & initialize a curl session
        $curl = curl_init();

        // set our url with curl_setopt()
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.tg3ds.com/api/v1/scan_records?apikey=1sjQKWfPpdyxRBvfv2BuTl5JzexOIScCFN0t&limit=20&offset=0&sort=scanned_at&user_id=PGLY1096&unfold=true&filter=PGLY1096");

        // return the transfer as a string, also with setopt()
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // curl_exec() executes the started curl session
        // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($curl);
        var_dump($output);
        exit();
```

Comment: set curl [user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738097/how-to-deal-with-curl-403-forbidden-error-any-solutions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this curl call you have to set User Agent for example

> `$context = stream_context_create(
> array(
> "http" => array(
> "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
> )
> ) );

> $api_url = 'https://api.tg3ds.com/api/v1/scan_records?apikey=1sjQKWfPpdyxRBvfv2BuTl5JzexOIScCFN0t&limit=20&offset=0&sort=scanned_at> &user_id=PGLY1096&unfold=true&filter=PGLY1096';
> $json_data = file_get_contents($api_url, false,
> $context);`